# VBA - Unexpected ObjectType leading to error

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

my code is below. narDocument is throwing on error on

```
narDocument.Quit False
```

The error is "Runtime Error 438: Object doesn't support this object or method"

When I check the object type of narDocument, it's type 8, which is a String.

So it makes sense that an object of type String wouldn't have the method .Quit, but my question is - why is this a String in the first place? I can't see where it's actually assigned to being a String, and all the rest of the code works as intended... which I think would be the case if this was indeed a String. Thanks!

```
Public Sub testing_1()

Dim narApplication As Word.Application
Dim narDocument As Word.Document
Set narApplication = CreateObject("word.application")
Set narDocument = narApplication.Documents.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "/document_template.docx")

MsgBox VarType(narDocument)

Dim TITLE As String
Dim myRange As Word.range
Dim myFind As Word.Find
Dim filePath As String

TITLE = range("B1")

'For each value, find it's value in the blankdocument
Set myRange = narDocument.Content
Set myFind = myRange.Find
With myFind
    .Text = "__TITLE__"
    searchResult = .Execute
End With

MsgBox VarType(narDocument)

narDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=myRange, Address:="http://www.google.com", TextToDisplay:=TITLE

filePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "/document_test.docx"
narDocument.SaveAs2 Filename:=filePath

MsgBox VarType(narDocument)

' Cleanup
narDocument.Quit False
Set narApplication = Nothing
Set narDocument = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: You `.Close` a document. You `.Quit` an application.

Comment: An object passed to `VarType` will return its default property type, which is probably path or name.

Comment: BTW if you actually wnt the name of the type, try TypeName()

Even that may not get it right, e.g. if you assiagn a Document to a Variant you'll probably be "back to the seeing the name of the default member", i.e. "String" in this case).

Answer (score 0):

You get 8 from VarType as the default property of a Document object is its Name property which returns a String.

Assuming you want to close the Document without saving and then quit Word, amend your line

```
narDocument.Quit False
```

to

```
narDocument.Close False
narApplication.Quit
```